# Why Jquery skips validation and shows success?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have jquery which I am using to validate , it skips the validate and it shows success , yet  I have typed no values in the text fields as it has to be . anybody who can help please do.

Here is my jquery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/zjquery.validate.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js">
</script>

</script>
<style type="text/css">
  label.valid {
    color: green !important; // !important added  
  } 
  label.error { 
    float: none; 
    color: red; 
    padding-left: .5em; 
    vertical-align: top;  
  }

</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#results').hide();
    $("#contactform").validate({
      debug: false,
      rules: {
        fname: "required",
        subject: "required",
        email: "required",
        message: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        Paymentfrequency: "Select frequency",
        fname: "Type name ",
        subject: "Type surname ",
        email: "invalid email",     
        message: "Select loan type",                
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('mailmeform.php', $("#contactform").serialize(), function(data) {
          $('#contactform').fadeOut("slow");  
          $('#results').fadeIn(2000);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

below is the HTML

```
<table name="contacttable" border="0" width="100%">
<form id="contactform" action="mailmeform.php" method = "post">
<table>
  <tr><td><label>Name:</label></td><td><input type = "text" name = "fname"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><label>Subject:</label></td><td><input type = "text" name = "subject"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><label class="required">Email:</label></td><td><input type = "text" name = "email" ></td></tr>
  <tr><td><label>message:</label></td><td><textarea cols = 40 rows=5 name = "message"></textarea></td></tr> 
  <tr><td><input type = "submit" value = "send"></td></tr>
  </h3>
</form><tr>
<td><div id ="results"><p>Thanks We will be back to you soon</p></div></td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: Please format code in a readable format.

Comment: @Simon the Edit was appreciated thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INVALID HTML** is why the validation was broken.  Mismatched tags, unclosed tags, stray `</h3>` and `</div>` tags inside the `table`, but the critical error was how you wrapped the `<form>` tag around your `<table>`...

```
<table name="contacttable" border="0" width="100%">
    <form id="contactform" action="mailmeform.php" method = "post">
        <table>
            <tr>...</tr>
            <tr>...</tr>
    </h3>
    </form>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

Once this HTML is cleaned up, the jQuery Validate plugin works fine:

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/p2kLR/**

---

Also, you've included the plugin twice.  Remove the second instance...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js">
```

and you've included jQuery twice, remove the older version...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

Something more like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You using a Jquery Validate Plugin [Jquery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Just try to add class like on demo:

```
class="required"
class="required email"
```

You added Jquery Validation scripst two times. Remove one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js">
```

Comment: Prisz it does not change anything you cant believe

Comment: @Norbart Pisz 100% to be honesty I do not know how to check for error in js

Comment: In Chrome ctrl+shift+c, in firefox ctrl+shift+k. And go Console Tab, then reload page and check errors.

Comment: No errors detected really I do not know whats going on with this code

Answer (score -1):

try form validate on button click

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){

//your code

and if true 
$('#results').show();
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#results').hide();
});
```